# Data from express session is being renewed/refreshed on each request when testing it with client side

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, axios, express-session

I'm trying to achieve that the session data is successfully saved while testing with axios service. I'm was trying to put `withCredentials:true` in axios service but it still doesn't help. The thing that bothers me is that the value of each request which is intended for the same Cookie's name/session ID is different. I tested this on server-side with Postman and value of cookies is always the same so this is the reason why this works just fine on express service.

This is the session middleware

```
app.use(session({
name: "session-id",
secret: "hideSession",
saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: false,
  httpOnly: true,
  cookie: {
     maxAge: 60*10000*200*10,
     sameSite: 'none',
     secure: true,
  },
```

}));

For better understanding:

```
let Service = axios.create({ 
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3005/',  
});
```

This is my client side code when I'm passing the request with using axios:

```
let Cart = {
    addToCart(name){
        Service.post(`/add_to_cart/${name}`)
    }
```

Function with fetching axios request data (from another file but still in client-side):

```
async sendCartData(name){
            Cart.addToCart(name);
        }
```

And the button:

```
<p @click="sendCartData(item.name)" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</p>
```

Comment: Probably because of `expires`?

Comment: That's not the issue in my case, before I removed ```expires``` and nothing changes.

Comment: And what is cookie expiration date without it?

Comment: What exactly should I put in ```expires``` then?

Comment: This is primarily Node/Express question, while you asked it for front end. I fixed the tags. Please, specify what is cookie expiration value in a browser in both cases. This is what affects how it works and can explain the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826792/node-express-session-expiration

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a look and inform you if it works for me.

Comment: I updated my question what I did with the session middleware, still this doesn't help...

Comment: maxAge is supposed to be a property of cookie. maxAge doesn't work like ` Date.now() + (30 * 86400 * 1000)`. You can just copy and paste the code from dupe question. You still didn't provide expiration date. It's truncated in the screenshot.

Comment: Can you help how to specify cookie expiration value in a browser?

Comment: It's done on server side exactly the way it's shown in dupe question. You need to specify expiration date from a browser in the question for clarity. It's truncated on the screenshot `Ex...`. Otherwise it's unclear what happens on your end

Comment: Okay now it's much clearer to me! Just did the request right now. This is my ```Expires/Max-Age```: 2022-08-24T11:29:05.000Z. How to show this in code for example?

Comment: Can be just a screenshot, or cookie data from request headers. I expect this to be changed when proper `cookie` Express param is specified

Comment: I set a screenshot in my question and the value of maxAge can be seen

Comment: I see. How does it correlate with maxAge value? You're setting it to 50 seconds which looks unreasonably low value that doesn't allow to debug the problem with sessions

Comment: Well I'm confused, I told you wrong, it actually expires 2 hours before my timezone now.

Comment: What could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The setting [`secure: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#secure) means that the cookie will only be set over HTTPS, but you use HTTP (http://localhost:3005/).

Either switch to HTTPS, or remove both `secure: true` and `sameSite: "none"` (because the latter requires the former).

Comment: Even with ```secure: false``` works the same

Comment: You cannot have `sameSite: "none"` and `secure: false` at the same time.